# Excel VB Macro - Find and Delete row with specific data plus the 4 rows above it

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this!!

I am trying to create a macro, which will be placed on the Quick Access Toolbar to find and delete a row where Column P = "Service to Claim Count 1" plus the 4 rows above it.

The file is several thousand entries long so I need it to go through the entire document and delete all 5 rows (the main row with the search data, plus the 4 above).

I hope you can help! :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to find, in column P, a cell that has `Service to Claim Count 1`, then delete that row *and* the four rows above it?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Please tell me that is possible! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub delRows()
Dim txtCel As Range
Dim timesFound As Long, i As Long
timesFound = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("P:P"), "Service to Claim Count 1")
For i = 1 To timesFound
    Set txtCel = Columns(16).Find(what:="Service to Claim Count 1")
    txtCel.Offset(-4).Select
    Range(txtCel, txtCel.Offset(-4)).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

Pretty straight forward. It finds the cell with the text, then deletes that row, and the four above it.

Comment: Yes, there will be many rows that are blank in Column P.

Each "Record" is 5 Rows long. Row 1 will always be a number, Row 2 will have Service to Claim Count 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5, and Rows 3, 4 and 5 will always be blank.

Comment: @TimothyGould - If row 2 has "Service to Claim Count 1", how do you expect to delete the previous 4 rows? Or, at most, do you want to delete previous 4 rows, and if it's less than that, so be it?

Comment: By removing the previous 4 rows, and the row that contains "Service to Claim Count 1" than it will bring it up to the previous "record" and remove all blank rows above it. The above Macro works, but is there a way I can make it repeat? There are thousands of records that need to be removed.

Comment: @TimothyGould - Oh, so "Service to..." can appear multiple times in column P? And you want to remove that and the prev. four rows for each occurrence?

Comment: Yes, that is it exactly!

Comment: You Are Batman.

That worked perfectly, I gave your code an upvote, but I think because I am new (not at 15 rep) it would not publicly show.

Thanks SO MUCH!!

Comment: @TimothyGould - Happy to help! You can mark it as the "Answer" by clicking the outline of the check mark just left of the post (below the up/down vote). That will signal to other folks that your question was answered :D

Comment: @YowE3K - good call, noted. Wouldn't it throw an error though? Not to expand the scope of the macro, but perhaps I should account for error handling? Or if it sees `For i = 1 to 0` does it just skip the loop? (I'm away from comp. and can't remember off the top of my head).